# Undefined responseText from XHR in sidebar gadget

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm trying to write a gadget that displays the current temperature from api.openweathermap.org.
The gadget pulls the info via an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest in a setTimeout "loop" (so the weather data updates every few minutes), but sometimes the XHR's responseText is undefined, which of course throws an error and stops the loop and, inevitably, the update process.

Fiddler shows the traffic goes out and the response comes back with a valid and expected data, yet the XHR cannot somehow access it.

The relevant JS bits:

```
var timer;      // these three 
var locStr;     // are defined 
var weather;    // elsewhere

function showWeather()
{
    System.Debug.outputString('showWeather()');
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    locStr = System.Gadget.Settings.readString("location");

    // this is for first-run use only - when the setting is not set, display an appropriate notification to the user
    if (locStr == "")
    {
        cell.style.display = 'none';
        welcome.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        cell.style.display = 'block';
        welcome.style.display = 'none';

        updateWeather();
    }
}

function updateWeather()
{
    System.Debug.outputString('updateWeather()');
    try
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            System.Debug.outputString('updateWeather()>onreadystatechange ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.readyState);
            if (xhr.status === 200)
            {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4)
                {
                    // this is what makes it fail:
                    System.Debug.outputString(xhr.responseText);
                    weather = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')'); // i DO get that eval is evil, but works for my purposes well.

                    // temp, city, wind and clouds are html entities id values
                    temp.innerHTML = Math.round(weather.main.temp) + '<span>&deg;C</span>';
                    city.innerHTML = weather.name;
                    wind.innerHTML = weather.wind.speed + ' m/s';
                    clouds.innerHTML = weather.clouds.all + '%';

                    // clears and hides error, if occured in previous fetch
                    error_title.innerHTML = '';
                    error_description.innerHTML = '';
                    error.style.display = 'none';

                    timer = setTimeout(updateWeather, 1000 * 5);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp.innerText += '.';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                error_title.innerText = 'Connectivity error';
                error_description.innerText = xhr.status + '.'; // that's really informative...
                error.style.display = 'block';

                timer = setTimeout(updateWeather, 5000)
            }
        };
        xhr.ontimeout = function()
        {
            error_title.innerText = 'Connectivity error';
            error_description.innerText = 'timed out';
            error.style.display = 'block';

            timer = setTimeout(updateWeather, 5000);
        };
        xhr.open('get', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + locStr + '&units=metric&dummy=' + Math.ceil(100*Math.random()), false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        xhr.send();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        error_title.innerText = e.name;
        error_description.innerText = e.message;
        error.style.display = 'block';

        timer = setTimeout(updateWeather, 5000);
    }
}
```

`showWeather()` is invoked in the window's onload event, which then checks whether the user has the location (city) set in preferences and starts the loop in updateWeather().

`updateWeather()` then makes the request and processes the data appropriately, which works, but as long as I don't try to access responseText.

I'm at my wit's end with this problem, but I feel like I'm missing something elementary here, and I'm not very experienced with JS yet.

I want to use pure javascript here, no fancy libraries for me.

Please advise.

**Update**

I did some changing and testing and here is what i found out:

1. I've used a different web service - Yahoo! Weather and the gadget worked flawlessly. Yahoo returns XML, OpenWeatherApi - JSON. I don't yet know if it's related to my issues, because as I've said before - OWA sometimes works.
2. CORS is definitely not an issue with gadgets. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Msn/) fiddle fails to retrieve the data, and in the inspector I can see a message stating that

   ```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=526363&u=c.
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
   Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
   ```

   Yet in my gadget, the data is retrieved without problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the cross domain security policy (Cross Origin Resource Sharing – CORS, W3C) mechanism implemented within browsers. HTTP requests via javascript for resources from a different domain will fail (you can get around this using JSONP, if the server supports it). To enable CORS, the server you are trying to connect to  needs to add your domain to the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" HTTP header or allow all domains (indicated using the asterisk wildcard '*').

MDN article for reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Someone has already logged this issue: http://bugs.openweathermap.org/issues/152

Comment: I believe the Same Origin Policy is not enforced in a gadget environment. To back up my claim - the gadget works at first, for the first three or so `updateWeather()` invocations the `responseText` field is accessible. And then it just isn't, which is what leaves me scratching my head.

Comment: Hmm ok, sounds exactly like the same problem that occurs with CORS in browsers, there are no errors and the response is correct when inspecting the network traffic but the javascript cant access it. Im not familiar with building windows gadgets but I assumed they ran in some kind of chromeless browser? I guess checking the header info in Fiddler may be helpful.